# How can I make a custom dojo widget themeable?

Tags: dojo

In dojo 1.8 I'm creating some custom application-specific widgets, and I want them to match the style of the page's current theme. Unfortunately, since my widgets are not composed of Dijit widgets, I haven't been able to figure out how to make that happen.

I'd like to be able to create my widgets' styles in terms of the `variables.less` variables; however, since I can't know which theme to use at build time I can't know which `variables.less` file to use. Additionally, although the `variables.less` file defines colors, it doesn't define other aspects of a theme such as border radius, spacing, etc.

The other approach that comes to mind is to find existing CSS classes defined by the themes that approximate what I want, and applying them to my HTML. That seems limiting, though, and sounds likely to be brittle.

The standard widgets seem to handle this by having each theme "know" about each widget that they'd want to display. I'd prefer not to need to modify each of the themes, although it's an acceptable fall-back if needed.

Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: Did you try to use the css classes dojo uses internally to make its widgets work / themed ?

Comment: No, because I don't know whether they're "stable". If they're private implementation details, they might change out from under me as the dijit package is modified over time. In particular, I'm concerned about the 2.0 change. If these classes are considered part of the public API, though, then they'd be suitable for at least most of what I need. Any idea which is the case?

Comment: i do not know this either, i am also going to face this problem soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `layke_` on the `#dojo` IRC, CSS classes can change even in minor version updates, but that it rarely requires refactoring of custom widgets--generally only if there's a major DOM restructuring in dijit. Based on that information, it appears that using the `dijit`* CSS classes is the way to go.